# how to work with gesture detector and how to create draggable top bar

Tags: dart, flutter

When I try to make an android status bar like a top bar in my app I use a gesture detector but I don't know how to proceed with it. How do I hide the container above and get the container while swiping like below:

[image]

How do I do something after a swipe ends and measure the swipe distance. The top bar should settle down or up and not stay in-between. How do I animate it to make it do it similar to how it is now. I tried `onVerticalDrag` etc but I don't have an idea how to it.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter Slivers can do that for you.

Check the following code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body:NestedScrollView(
          headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool _) {
            return <Widget>[
              SliverAppBar(
                expandedHeight: 200.0,
                floating: true,
                pinned: true,
                snap: true,
                flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                  centerTitle: true,
                  title: Text("Collapsing Toolbar",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ];
          },
          body: Center(
            child: Text("My Fancy Text"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering but my thoughts was the draggable screen should be stacked on top  of the original screen one should open that when needed by dragging from the top and swipe up to close it