# How to make a gesture driven animation in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am new to `Flutter` and currently, I am trying to make a swipeable bottom panel which animate the opacity of some text (just for now).

This is basically the animation I'm trying to achieve

[image]

I have found this answer by [Saed Nabil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53629168) which creates a bottom sheet and get its position.

How can I animate the `Text` according to drage percentage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on Saed Nabil response, I did some tweaks to his sample an used `TextStyle.lerp` to get a textstyle according to the dragged position.

```dart
StreamController<double> controller = StreamController.broadcast();

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

const defaultTextStyle = TextStyle(
  color: Colors.blue,
  fontSize: 15,
);

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  double position;
  TextStyle textStyle = defaultTextStyle;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final maxPosition = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 300;
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Show Buttom Sheet'),
            onPressed: () {
              showModalBottomSheet(
                  isScrollControlled: true,
                  context: context,
                  builder: (context) {
                    return StreamBuilder(
                      stream: controller.stream,
                      builder: (context, snapshot) => GestureDetector(
                          onVerticalDragUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
                            position = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
                                details.globalPosition.dy;
                            double newPosition = position;
                            if (position.isNegative || position == 0)
                              Navigator.pop(context);
                            else {
                              if (position > maxPosition) {
                                newPosition = maxPosition;
                              }
                              controller.add(newPosition);
                            }

                            textStyle = TextStyle.lerp(
                                defaultTextStyle,
                                TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontSize: 24,
                                ),
                                newPosition / maxPosition);
                          },
                          behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                          child: Container(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            height: snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data : 50.0,
                            width: double.infinity,
                            child: Text(
                              'Reviews',
                              style: textStyle,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            ),
                          )),
                    );
                  });
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Result

[image]

Comment: Hey your code is working fine but when i'm dragging `showModalBottomSheet` i'm getting below error `A RenderFlex overflowed by 3.5 pixels on the bottom.` any idea?

Comment: yes, it should be related to this line : final maxPosition = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 300;   I used a fixed number '300' only for the sample but you should calculate that value based on the size of your screen, maybe :  final maxPosition = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8;

Comment: still getting same exception after using `final maxPosition = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8;` check screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdZGv.png

Comment: Then could be the size of the text

Comment: Any solution for this or i should decrease the size of text

Comment: i checked your answer, how we can bring the smoothy drag effect into this?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what solution you are using for your modal bottom sheet you should be able to isolate a variable that changes according to the sheet. Usually this is achieved through a `controller` which some widgets provide or, in the case of Saed Nabil, he fed that variable into a custom one.

As long as you have the variable you should be able to provide simple math to an Opacity widget over your Text widget with something like this.

Assuming your variable goes from 0, 0.1, 0.111, 0.222.....1. You can do something like this:

```
double opacity = 1 - controller.position;

Opacity(
  opacity: opacity,
  child: Text(),
);
```

Comment: Well, I thought about this but the position is something like 680. Indeed there is a work around for this and your solution is legit as well. Thank you.